# $conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME); - not working

Tags: php, mysql, database, connection

Whenever I try this,

```
$conn = mysqli_connect(example.com,user,password,database);
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. My php version is php 5.3.above. Why is this code not working in a live website. Its fine in localhost.

Comment: is mysqli installed/enabled in the php?

Comment: Also, try it with the port number.

Comment: Explain not working. Did you test that the `$conn` was not false?

Comment: Define "not working". What happens or doesn't happen?

Comment: I tried both, mysql/mysqli

Comment: Can you please use `mysqli_error()` to get the error?

Comment: Whilst this does not answer your question, may I advise you to start using PDO or MySQLi. The `mysql_*` functions are now deprecated, therefore writing applications with them is not a great idea. See here for more info: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'user'@'example-host.com' (using password: YES) in /home/morecamb/public_html/includes/config.php on line 26
Could not connect: Access denied for user 'user'@'example-host.com' (using password: YES) . This is the error i get. This happened when i tried mysql instead of mysqli

Comment: Sounds like a bad username and/or password

Comment: @subash90 The clue is in the error!!! You are using the wrong username or password!

Comment: ... or the user has a `GRANT` with that password, but not from the host you are connecting via.

Comment: I'm pretty much sure about using the username or password, cause i copied and pasted that

Comment: @BenCarey there is a request being made using MySQLI not MYSQL

Comment: I'm still trying. What should be the values of hostname,username,password or other thing in live site? Suppose my site is example.com. Are there any rules? I'm using cpanel.

Comment: chances are your db server is running on localhost so change the DB_HOST define to localhost.  Also check you've setup a user correctly and flushed the privlidges of the mysql server to commit the user changes

Comment: I'm getting this now. Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
define('DB_HOST','example.com');
```

should be

```
define('DB_HOST','localhost');
```

With `localhost` you are saying that PHP has to connect to the MySQL server that is running on the same server. 
Unless you are trying to connect to a remove MySQL server, then you'll have to fill in the address of that remote server.

Comment: I get this 
    Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()

Comment: Are you sure that mysqli is enabled in php? Check if it listed in the phpinfo();